# The textures of a model do not bake into a single new UVmap

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

I imported in Blender a .fbx file from Unity. It's a jungle hexagonal tile made of many meshes that I joined together to form a single object. I've been trying to bake all the textures in one UV map so that, once imported the .obj file, I can get all the textures in Tabletop simulator. Problem is that after baking the new texture image I'm baking onto, the image is still all black, as it was before baking. I don't understand what is going wrong. Here's how I went about it:

1. create a new UVmap
2. select it and Smart unwrap the object
3. pack islands
4. create a new black image texture (size 2048-2048 - No alpha)
5. With the old UV map on and the new one selected, I went to the node editor of each original atlas and added a UV map with the new UV map as content, connecting it to a Texture image with the new texture image. I also added a UV map with the old UV map connecting to the main texture image.
6. with the new image texture node selected in each atlas I baked (diffuse, no direct and indirect) but the new texture is still all black!
   Here's a pic of the node editor of one of the many atlas. I think that the problem must be here somewhere.
   [image]

Comment: Unless you are going for lighting effects, don't bake diffuse. Try to use nothing but an emission shader (and your textures) and bake the emission pass.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.